# Creating Custom .NET Object Maps from JSON strings

Tags: c#

I dread coding this but has anyone coded this before or are you using a 3rd party lib like Json.NET?  I'd prefer to code my own parser and just wondering what others have done to parse Json and handle that generically.

Comment: If you *dread* coding it, why would you prefer to write your own parser?

Comment: As always, more flexible, no reliance on anyone else breaking it, or non-support for whatever.  We don't like to use a lot of 3rd party reliance for obvious reasons.

Comment: I also have more control at the lowest level and performance I can ensure myself...I don't have to go hack up a 3rd party code base.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: so you're not even going to *consider* saving yourself time by using an existing library? How is it that you're comfortable relying on the .NET framework?

Comment: Here's the thing.  My boss won't let me use a 3rd party.  So that kinda leaves me to coding my own anyway and it would be a good challenge/learning process.  I prefer to write my own because I can control it more.  Your question about the .NET framework and relying on that is bogus.  Eveyrone relies on that, what do you want me to do go write my own freaking programming language?  You're talking about a programming LANGUAGE vs. a 3rd party open source FRAMEWORK.  Completely different and scope and reliance totally diferent.  Using too many 3rd party can cause problems and maint nightmares

Comment: I would rather roll my own than deal with a possible framework that a) some day may not be supported anymore b) has bugs that I did not create and I have to either wait for them to be fixed by the community or whatever c) I can control performance without having to tweak anything..just code it the way I want d) I can extend it probably with much less code than an entire framework if I only need to parse JSON to an object which is all I need here.

Comment: You don't think there's a lot of people relying on JSON parsers? Don't use your boss as an excuse. At the end of the day, it's your job to be saving your company money, even if that means disagreeing with your boss. I completely agree that taking a dependency on a third party library is not to be done without thought, but it sounds like you're forgoing all thought because "your boss says so".

Comment: Not saying there isn't.  Don't use my boss as an excuse?  Do you want to support me when I get fired and living on the streets?  Can you brush my teeth and feed my children because he WOULD fire me for that.  It's not a place you go against the grain.

Comment: I wasn't aware how complex parsing JSON is...now I know....grammars, etc.  My boss is the ONLY coder for this .com.  That is "THE TEAM".  So consider the situation before ranting.

Comment: Seriously, what? If I was in fear of being fired for putting forward recommendations based on the facts then I would rather quit and work elsewhere. I'm done with this thread - good luck with your job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started down the road 1 1/2 years ago (or so) with writing my own JSON parser, but then I ran across JSON.NET and have used it ever since.  I've used it on a number of projects and really haven't run into any issues.

Handling dates was the straw that broke the camel's back, so to speak, that drove me to JSON.NET.

Comment: interesting, what was the problem with handling of dates?  Just curious for my own knowledge